# Layer visibility toggle shortcut in Gimp

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gimp, layers

I have a lot of layers in my image. I need to go through them one by one and rename each one. When I'm on the **Layers** toolbox I can hit <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to quickly rename a layer. I would like to then **make it invisible** and move on to the next one by pressing <kbd>↓</kbd>.

**How to toggle layer visibility without using the mouse/touchpad?**

I know that clicking on a layer's visibility icon with <kbd>Shift</kbd> toggles between only this layer visible and all layers visible. That's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out:

1. Go to Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts.
2. Search for 'visibility'.
3. Assign something to 'Toggle Layer Visibility' (which is Disabled by default)

[image]